# VBA For loop + if statement error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a loop that finds the value of my input box, select the cell that has the matching value of my input box and delete its the entire row.
For some reason It seems like my if condition is not working at all.

*Totalrow= my double variable for the total number of rows on my sheet
*tenroxcode = my string variable for the inputbox

```
For i = 1 To totalrows
    If tenroxcode = Range("E" & i).Value Then
        Range("E" & i).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Could someone **PLEASE** help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop backwards:

```
For i = totalrows to 1 step -1
    If tenroxcode = Range("E" & i).Value Then Rows(i).Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate that should be significantly faster.

```
dim r as variant

r = application.match(tenroxcode, columns("E"), 0)
do while not iserror(r)
    rows(r).entirerow.delete
    r = application.match(tenroxcode, columns("E"), 0)
loop
```